# Clear query result when button is clicked

Tags: php, html

```
//html form
<p>Search Name of Applicants</p>
<form name ="searchForm" method="post" action="admin.php">
    <input name="searchIto" type="text" size ="40" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="submit" name="searchMo" value="Search"/>
    <input type="reset" name="resetMo" value="Clear"/>
</form>
//database connection
<?php
    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "applications";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";
    $db_handle = @mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = @mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
?>
//query
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['searchIto'])){
        header('Location:admin.php');
    }
    $search_sql="SELECT * FROM loanapplications WHERE firstName LIKE '%".$_POST['searchIto']."%' OR lastName LIKE '%".$_POST['searchIto']."%'";
    $search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=null){
        $search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
    }
?>
<p>Search Results</p>
<?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=null){
        do {
?>
<span>ID:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['loantype'];?><br>
<span>First Name:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['firstName'];?><br>
<span>Last Name:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['lastName'];?><br>
<?php
        } while($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
?>
```

I like to clear the query result if i clicked clear button and if I refresh the page, the query is still there, if I refresh or click or leave the admin page, the query will be cleared.

Comment: Just a note: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: see this , https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 0):

At the end of code write following code -

```
<?php 
 mysql_free_result($search_query);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in code,

Firstly Html add result div as wrapper for search result with clear button.

```
<button id="clear" value="clear" ></button>
    <div id="result">
        <p>Search Results</p>
        <?php
        if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=null){
        do{?>
        <span>ID:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['loantype'];?><br>
        <span>First Name:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['firstName'];?><br>
        <span>Last Name:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['lastName'];?><br>
        <?php
        }while($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));
        } 
        else{
        echo "No results found";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Now add some script for clearing search result

```
   <script>
        $("#clear").click(function (event) {
            $("#result").html(" <p>Search Results</p>"."No results found");

        });
    </script>
```

because of this you need to refresh page and you will successfully clear search result.